# Laravel Shared Hosting subfolder Vue js Page Link Not Working?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, hosting, shared, subdirectory

Laravel Vue Project

My project run from subfolder. project running successfully but when click a link. This link not working properly. 
example
clickable original link : **test.example.com/subfolder/service**
now link show : *test.example.com/service* (subfolder missing)

what's wrong ? Please help me.

Comment: please explain better . [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My project run from subfolder. project running successfully but when click page link. This link not working properly. example
clickable original link : test.example.com/subfolder/service
now link show : test.example.com/service